# Select from many-to-many table

Tags: sql, many-to-many

I have next table called `option_to_name` data:

```
+-----------+---------+
| option_id | name_id |
+-----------+---------+
| 1         | 1       |
| 1         | 2       |
| 2         | 2       |
| 3         | 2       |
+-----------+---------+
```

I need to select `name_id` which has relation with `1` and `2` values in `option_id`. I've tried to use `WHERE IN` but it works like `has 1 or has 2`.

```
SELECT name_id FROM option_to_name WHERE option_id IN (1, 2)
```

Is there any way to select `name_id` which has both `1` and `2` values in `option_id`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are close.  Just add some aggregation:

```
SELECT name_id
FROM option_to_name
WHERE option_id IN (1, 2)
GROUP BY name_id
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT option_id) = 2;
```

Comment: Nice idea! Thanks a lot!